# exception MyExc3 is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Tags: java, exception

I've already seen a similar question, but I haven't found a solution because in my case a function put in a try clause throw an exception actually.

```
    class MyExc1 extends Exception { }
    class MyExc2 extends MyExc1 { }
    class MyExc3 extends MyExc2 { }

    public class A1 {
     public static void main(String [] argv) {
     try {
      m();
     } catch( MyExc3 k ) {
         System.out.print(1);
     } catch( Exception u ) {
     } finally {
        throw( new Exception() );
      }
    }

    static void m() {
      try {
       System.out.print(2);
       throw( new MyExc3() );
    }catch( MyExc3 z ) {
    System.out.print(3);
    }catch( Exception d ) {
       System.out.print(4);
    }finally {
       System.out.print(5);
     }
    }
   }
```

In my try block, psv main invokes method `m();` which prints 2 and raises an exception named MyExc3. Then, this exception should be handle by the `catch(MyExcp3 z)` which should print 3 and so on. But the code actually does not compile:

> exception MyExc3 is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Why is that?

Comment: Is MyExc3 a checked or unchecked exception?  I’m going to guess checked, and that the compiler is complaining since pax main can never get that exception

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback. And welcome to upvote levels ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `throws` part on the method signature.

First of all, your code (as given right now) doesn't compile because your `main()` can throw `Exception`, but doesn't declare it. When you fix that, then the compiler tells you that `m()` doesn't throw a checked exception of class MyExc3.

Thus: add `throws Exception` to `public static void main(...)` and same for `m()`:

```
static void m() throws MyExc3 {
```

That is the point of checked exception: when your method uses `throw someCheckedExceptionInstance` ... then that must either be caught within that method or the method must *announce* via `throws TheSpecificExceptionType` that it throws that checked exception!

Answer (score 0):

finally is run always after running try and catch(if an exception occurs). So, in this case, there is nothing to handle your exception thrown from finally block. You can solve this either by adding this:

```
public static void main(String [] argv) throws Exception {
    try {
        m();
    } catch( MyExc3 k ) {
        System.out.print(1);
    } catch( Exception u ) {
    } finally {
        throw( new Exception() );
    }
}
```

or by doing this:

```
public static void main(String [] argv) {
    try {
        m();
    } catch( MyExc3 k ) {
        System.out.print(1);
    } catch( Exception u ) {
    } finally {
        try {
            throw( new Exception() );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But still, you will get a compilation error. That is because you are catching a **MyExc3** exception in main, where it is not thrown to main(). You threw a MyExc3 exception in m(). But you caught the exception in m() as well. So no MyExc3 exception has come in main(). For that, to throw a MyExc3 exception you need to add this:

```
 static void m() throws MyExc3 {
```